# how to get return value when using schedule

Tags: python

I have a scheduled task that runs using the schedule library. Where does the return value of my task go?

```
import requests, time, datetime, json, schedule 

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/reg/'

def get_registers(date):
    all_reg = {}
    full_page = requests.get(url, auth=("admin","admin"))
    pars=json.loads(full_page.content.decode('utf-8'))
    a=sorted(pars, key=lambda pars: pars['time_visit'])
    count=0
    for i in a:
        if i['date_visit']==date:
            count +=1
            all_reg.setdefault(i["number_car"] , i['time_visit'])
    return all_reg

now = datetime.datetime.now()

schedule.every(1).minutes.do(get_registers,date)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

How to get the return value after applying the function for further work with it?
If I do so `print(all_reg)` they are displayed, but I would like to work take off inside other functions.